# Tetris Random Generator: random.choice with permutations versus random.shuffle

Tags: python, algorithm, random

In some implementations of the game of Tetris, there is an algorithm called [Random Generator](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Generator) which generates an infinite sequence of permutations of the set of one-sided tetrominoes based on the following algorithm:

> Random Generator generates a sequence of all seven one-sided
>   tetrominoes (I, J, L, O, S, T, Z) permuted randomly, as if they were
>   drawn from a bag. Then it deals all seven tetrominoes to the piece
>   sequence before generating another bag.

Elements of this infinite sequence are only generated when necessary. i.e. a random permutation of 7 one-sided tetrominoes is appended to a queue of tetrominoes when more pieces are required than the queue can provide.

I believe there are two primary methods of doing this in Python.

The first method uses `itertools.permutations` and `random.choice`

```
import itertools, random, collections
bag = "IJLOSTZ"
bigbag = list(itertools.permutations(bag))
sequence = collections.deque(random.choice(bigbag))
sequence.extend(random.choice(bigbag))
sequence.extend(random.choice(bigbag))
# . . . Extend as necessary
```

The second method uses only `random.shuffle`.

```
import random, collections
bag = ['I', 'J', 'L', 'O', 'S', 'T', 'Z']
random.shuffle(bag)
sequence = collections.deque(bag)
random.shuffle(bag)
sequence.extend(bag)
random.shuffle(bag)
sequence.extend(bag)
# . . . Extend as necessary
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of either method, assuming that the player of Tetris is skilled and the Random Generator must produce a large sequence of one-sided tetrominoes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the time to shuffle a tiny list is simply trivial, so don't worry about it.  Either method should be "equally random", so there's no basis for deciding there.

But rather than muck with both lists and deques, I'd use a tile generator instead:

```
def get_tile():
    from random import shuffle
    tiles = list("IJLOSTZ")
    while True:
        shuffle(tiles)
        for tile in tiles:
            yield tile
```

Short, sweet, and obvious.

### Making that peekable

Since I'm old, when I hear "peekable queue" I think "circular buffer".  Allocate the memory for a fixed-size buffer once, and keep track of "the next item" with an index variable that wraps around.  Of course this pays off a lot more in C than in Python, but for concreteness:

```
class PeekableQueue:
    def __init__(self, item_getter, maxpeek=50):
        self.getter = item_getter
        self.maxpeek = maxpeek
        self.b = [next(item_getter) for _ in range(maxpeek)]
        self.i = 0

    def pop(self):
        result = self.b[self.i]
        self.b[self.i] = next(self.getter)
        self.i += 1
        if self.i >= self.maxpeek:
            self.i = 0
        return result

    def peek(self, n):
        if not 0 <= n <= self.maxpeek:
            raise ValueError("bad peek argument %r" % n)
        nthruend = self.maxpeek - self.i
        if n <= nthruend:
            result = self.b[self.i : self.i + n]
        else:
            result = self.b[self.i:] + self.b[:n - nthruend]
        return result

q = PeekableQueue(get_tile())
```

So you consume the next tile via `q.pop()`, and at any time you can get a list of the next `n` tiles that *will* be popped via `q.peek(n)`.  And there's no organic Tetris player in the universe fast enough for the speed of this code to make any difference at all ;-)

Comment: Oh and deques are better for this kind of thing because of O(1) popleft and append to the peek queue. Lists don't have that kind of efficiency. This kind of queue can be seen in http://www.tetrisfriends.com In some tetris implementations, they show the next piece coming up or the next k pieces. Thus you need to be able to view at most 2 permutations at once.

Comment: Ya, I know why a deque was being used.  With a generator, no pushing or popping or extending of any kind is needed.  Note that `deque.extend(bag)` isn't free!  That takes `O(len(bag))` time too.

Comment: Ah, replied before you finished your comment.  If you change the problem statement, then the answer can change too ;-)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I did that awkward Jeopardy thing where I stated the answer (collections.deque) before the question (peek queues). :\

Comment: Okay that circular array idea is just brilliant...With that I can just use a list of n elements to peek n ahead just by shifting a single index variable and populate the list with your efficient generator which is amortized O(1) per element. Perfect answer. :) And wow, circular buffers sounds like they could be really useful in C.

Comment: I will likely modify the generator to just do random.choice to avoid the shuffle computation, but otherwise I really like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are `7! = 5040` permutations of a sequence of 7 distinct objects. Thus, generating all permutations is very costly in terms of both time complexity (O(n!*n)) and space complexity (O(n!*n)). However choosing a random permutation from the sequence of permutations is easy. Let's look at the code for `choice` from [`random.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2e8b28dbc395/Lib/random.py#l272).

```
def choice(self, seq):
    """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
```

As you can see the calculation of the index is O(1) since `len(seq)` is O(1) for any sequence and `self.random()` is also O(1). Fetching an element from the list type in Python is also O(1) so the entire function is O(1).

---

On the other hand, using `random.shuffle` will swap the elements of your bag in-place. Thus it will use O(1) space complexity. However in terms of time complexity it is not so efficient. Let's look at the code for `shuffle` from [`random.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2e8b28dbc395/Lib/random.py#l276)

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.
    """

    if random is None:
        random = self.random
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

`random.shuffle` implements the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) which, "is similar to randomly picking numbered tickets out of a hat, or cards from a deck, one after another until there are no more left." However the number of computations are clearly greater than the first method since `len(x)-1` calls to `random()` must be made and it also requires `len(x)-1` swap operations. Each swap operation requires 2 fetches from the list and the generation of a 2-tuple for unpacking and assignment.

---

Based on all of this information, I would guess that the first method mentioned uses up a lot of memory to store the permutations and requires O(n!*n) time complexity overhead, but in the long-run it is probably much more efficient than the second method and will likely keep the framerate stable in an actual implementation of a Tetris game since there will be less computations to do during the actual game loop. The permutations can be generated before the display is even initialized which is nice for giving the illusion that your game does not perform many computations.

---

Here I post finalized code using Tim Peters' suggestion of a generator and a circular buffer. Since the size of the circular buffer would be known before the buffer's creation, and it would never change, I did not implement all of the features that circular buffers usually have (you can find that on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)). In any case, it works perfectly for the Random Generator algorithm.

```
def random_generator():
    import itertools, random
    bag = "IJLOSTZ"
    bigbag = list(itertools.permutations(bag))
    while True:
        for ost in random.choice(bigbag):
            yield ost


def popleft_append(buff, start_idx, it):
    """ This function emulates popleft and append from
        collections.deque all in one step for a circular buffer
        of size n which is always full,
        The argument to parameter "it" must be an infinite 
        generator iterable, otherwise it.next() may throw
        an exception at some point """
    left_popped = buff[start_idx]
    buff[start_idx] = it.next()
    return (start_idx + 1) % len(buff), left_popped


def circular_peek(seq, start_idx):
    return seq[start_idx:len(seq)] + seq[:start_idx]


# Example usage for peek queue of size 5
rg = random_generator()
pqsize = 5
# Initialize buffer using pqsize elements from generator
buff = [rg.next() for _ in xrange(pqsize)]
start_idx = 0
# Game loop
while True:
    # Popping one OST (one-sided tetromino) from queue and 
    # adding a new one, also updating start_idx
    start_idx, left_popped = popleft_append(buff, start_idx, rg)
    # To show the peek queue currently
    print circular_peek(buff, start_idx)
```

Comment: FYI, if you disassemble the bytecode produced by any recent version of CPython, you'll see that 2-tuples are no longer generated for swaps.  Not that it actually matters - LOL ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters I updated the answer to include code which implemented your suggestion. It's a bit modified using 2 primitive functions instead of a class, but generally the same idea for a peek queue of size 5. Thanks a lot for teaching me about circular buffers. :) They seem to be very useful for SPOJ problems involving queues because most problems have a fixed maximum size for the queue. Because of this, I don't have to implement a dynamic-memory queue in C, I can just use a constant compile-time array of maximal size and 3 pointers + a size variable. :D Which is much easier IMO.

Comment: Cool! Note that you could profitably make popleft_append a generator too, like `def popleft_append(buff, it): i = 0; n = len(buff); while True:; result = buff[i]; buff[i] = next(it); i = (i+1) % n; yield result`. Then the current index is saved in the generator's internal state as a fast local vrbl (and likewise for `len(buff)`), and the game logic doesn't have to know anything about it.